# output java: calculate the weight for each friend

Tags: java, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

the output of my java class is as follows:

```
created time Thu Jun 15 03:52:53 CEST 2017 
Id Poste: fb.com/1562752627337463_1951227231823332 
le poid de l'interaction Wint 1.0 
Fifi Daly Omm Omar 
Toka Ep Bouzidi 
=================================== 
created time Wed Jun 14 21:14:14 CEST 2017 
Id Poste: fb.com/1562752627337463_1951069731839082 
le poid de l'interaction Wint 0.9 
Sami Dali 
Toka Ep Bouzidi 
Àmine OuLéd Ahméd 
Faiza Ouled Ahmed 
Rania Trigui 
Hàifà Gassoumi 
Awatef Cherif 
Dali Montassar 
Souad Brahmi 
Nabiha Ben Aissa 
Deli Maha 
=================================== 
created time Wed Jun 14 19:39:27 CEST 2017 
Id Poste: fb.com/149760905397346_444326185940815 
le poid de l'interaction Wint 0.9 

=================================== 
created time Wed Jun 14 01:26:57 CEST 2017 
Id Poste: fb.com/1562752627337463_1950398421906213 
le poid de l'interaction Wint 0.7 
Nesrine Jalleli 
Esmeralda Sagittaire 
Aymen J'rb 
===================================
```

And I have another class that shows me the names of all my friends: the output is as follows:

```
**Sami Dali 
Toka Ep Bouzidi 
Àmine OuLéd Ahméd 
Faiza Ouled Ahmed 
Rania Trigui 
Hàifà Gassoumi 
Awatef Cherif 
Dali Montassar 
Souad Brahmi 
Nabiha Ben Aissa 
Deli Maha 
Nesrine Jalleli 
Esmeralda Sagittaire 
Aymen J'rb 
etc..**
```

My problem is how I can calculate the sum of weights for each friend
Here is my java code:

```
import com.restfb.Connection;
import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
import com.restfb.types.Post;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       String accessToken ="EAACEdEose0cBANEXpFEXQZALRTI8k84B2po0w";
       FacebookClient fbclient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
       Connection<Post> result = fbclient.fetchConnection("me/feed",Post.class );
       int counter = 0;
  for(List<Post> page : result)
  {
        for(Post aPost : page)
            {    
                 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                 Calendar a = Calendar.getInstance();
                 a.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);
                 Date Fin = a.getTime();
                 Date db = c.getTime();
                 Date time = aPost.getCreatedTime();
                 double CONST_DURATION_OF_DAY = 1000l * 60 * 60 * 24;
                 double diff = Math.abs(db.getTime() - time.getTime());
                 double numberOfDay = Math.round((diff/CONST_DURATION_OF_DAY) * 
                  100) / 100;
                 double numberofyear = (double) Math.round((numberOfDay/356) * 100) 
                  / 100;
                double dbwint = (100-(numberofyear*10))/100 ;
                double Wint  = (double) Math.round( dbwint * 100) / 100;

      if(!time.before(Fin))
       {

System.out.println("created time     "+time+"\r\n");
System.out.println("Id Poste: fb.com/"+aPost.getId()+"\r\n");
System.out.println("le poid de l'interaction Wint  "+Wint+"\r\n");
Optional.ofNullable(aPost .flatMap(post -> Optional.ofNullable(post.getLikes()))
    .flatMap(likes -> Optional.ofNullable(likes.getData()))
    .ifPresent(likes -> likes.stream()
    .map(likeItem -> Optional.ofNullable(likeItem.getName()))
    .forEach(optName -> optName.ifPresent(name ->
     System.out.println(name + "\r\n"))));

System.out.println("==================================="+"\r\n");

counter++;

       }
 else {System.out.println("date hors période"+"\r\n");}

}
  System.out.println("number of results"+counter);

}
  }
   }
    }
```

Comment: its a question for algorithm with java, why you tagged javascript here? and why not java?

Comment: sorry Typing error

Comment: This code is extremely poorly written, and hard to read. Please indent 4 spaces. Also please provide the shortest example you can. I fell most of this code is irrelevant.

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. How are the outputs relevant to the question ?  Please post [mcve] (are you trying to calculate weight ? or age ?)

Comment: my question is how to calculate the sum of weight for each friend:                                                                                                        **Exemple:** my friend **Toka Ep Bouzidi**  have a weight= 1.0+0.9 = 1.9